# Device model detection and comparation doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I need to detect device model, and if it is Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i, print it out. But it never print's it (it doesn't get through condition).

My code:

```
public String mDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

System.out.println(mDeviceModel); //this prints my GT-S5830i

if (mDeviceModel == "GT-S5830i") //compiler don't get thru this cond.
    System.out.println("GALAXY ACE S5830i"); //never printed
```

I can't get what's wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a classic string comparison bug. In java "==" compares the object references to each other to see if they are the same object. In this case the string you just created for the comparison and the string `android.os.Build.MODEL` are two completely different string/objects even though their content may be the same. To compare the content of two strings, use the strings `equals()` method.

```
if (mDeviceModel == "GT-S5830i")
    System.out.println("GALAXY ACE S5830i");
```

Should read

```
if (mDeviceModel.equals("GT-S5830i"))
    System.out.println("GALAXY ACE S5830i"); // Should now print.
```